# Why is Carol unable to understand English?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

After Carol Danvers (still going as Vers) crashes into the Blockbuster, she meets a security guard who has trouble understanding her so she asks to herself if her "universal translator" is working. Presumably she needed the translator because she was unable to understand English without it. 
 We don't exactly know what the Kree did to her when they captured her, but it definitely involved some sort of artificial amnesia. Most amnesiacs still retain core level memories like motor functions and *language skills*. 
 According to that, Carol should have been able to understand the security guard even without her translator. Did the Kree somehow manage to erase her ability to understand English? If they didn't, why was the guard not able to understand her?

Comment: "it definitely involved some sort of artificial amnesia" What makes you so definitively sure that it was artificial? She was a victim of a very violent plane crash followed by an explosion of a... well an interstellar space ship engine... from a distance of about 30 feet. Enduring that kind of physical trauma to the head/body is perfectly likely to cause amnesia.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Carol had no problem understanding the guard. And the guard had no problem understanding her.

The issue that Carol thought she had, was caused by pure confusion on the guards side, as the guard just witnessed some pretty freaky stuff and was still shocked by it. The guard simply didn't respond in a timely manner (actually not really at all), which made Carol think that the guard didn't understand her.

Comment: You can also put in your answer, that is because Carol thought she was an alien and didn't have memories of being a human from earth.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel she had the memories and even saw them while on the Skrull ship, which was before she came to earth. Still debatable how that factors into it

Comment: She saw the images on the screens on the Skrull ship, but I think she didn't fully know she was from earth.

Comment: IIRC she also was asking something that was in English, but not something that would really have made sense to a 90s security guard.

Comment: On the basis that Carol exhibited pretty much no culture shock anywhere else, I assumed that this was intended humour on her part